# can't see distribution tab as a admin of ios

Tags: ios, distribution

I am Admin for iOS Development, BUT only a member in Safari Development . I can't see distribution tab, but I want to create a Ad HOC.

Is there any method to resolve it without a Safari Admin authority ?

Comment: You should see distribution tab no matter what. Agent,Admin,Members see distribution,development tabs in iOS Provisioning portal. Can you  show us screenshot ?

Comment: of course, here them are: [picture link1](http://tu.6.cn/pic/play-tu/id/0#14498727)  [picture link2](http://tu.6.cn/pic/play-tu/id/0#14498727)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like the only way is become the admin of safari.